# How to solve the error "Division of an OptimizationVariable by nonscalar not supported" in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

```
PowerFlow.Constraints.SOC = optimconstr(n);                  
  for j=1:n   
   if j==1
    PowerFlow.Constraints.SOC = SOC(j) == SOCini;
   else
    PowerFlow.Constraints.SOC(j) = SOC(j) == SOC(j-1)+((Ppvb(j-1)*eta_pvb)-(Pbe(j-1)*eta_d))/Cnew*(100*dT);            
    end

for z = 1:d
            if z==1
              Cnew(z) = Cnom;
            else
              Cnew(z) = Cnew(z-1)-0.00005;
            end
    end
```

Hi, I have met the following problem in MATLAB. This constraint regards the SOC of the battery. At the moment I've considered a constant loss for the capacity of the battery (Cbew); this value is used in the PowerFlow.constraints and changes every day.
When I ran the code the error says: "Division of an OptimizationVariable by nonscalar not supported".

Appreciate your help!

Comment: On what line does the error occur? Anyway, it's fairly self-explanatory that you're trying to divide your `OptimizationVariable` by something that isn't a scalar. I can understand MATLAB not liking that. Probably one of your variables is a matrix, check the sizes of each.

Comment: Sorry, the line where the error occur is: "PowerFlow.Constraints.SOC(j) = SOC(j) == SOC(j-1)+((Ppvb(j-1)*eta_pvb)-(Pbe(j-1)*eta_d))/Cnew*(100*dT)". My variables are arrays. Should I use something diffrent than linprog to solve my problem?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with relevant information, because comment are ephemeral and the formatting makes it difficult to read. Well, you know what your goal with the program is, we don't. If your variables are arrays, then yes, that's not a scalar and will cause this function to error out as mentioned. So probably you should use a different function indeed. Please see [ask] and [mcve] and make sure than *we* can run your code (provide sample input) and make clear what the desired result it.